# Xamarin Forms Android - Picker accepting free text

Tags: android, forms, xamarin, picker

I'm not sure if this is by design, or a bug - but in Android, a Picker control seems to allow the user to type in any old text, i.e. not limit the selection to just the ItemsSource collection.

Click on a Picker. It's list of items will be displayed. Click Cancel to dismiss the list. Notice the picker still has focus. Type on the physical keyboard of the device. The text typed in will appear in the Picker! The SelectedIndex won't fire etc so the Picker actually doesn't have any selected item, but that text appearing will stay there even if you move focus to another control - obviously giving the appearance that something is selected!

To reproduce, display the following page. Click the "Select a monkey" picker so the list appears. Click Cancel to dismiss the list. Focus still remains on the picker. Type some random text in the picker. The text appears in the picker, giving the appearance that the text you've typed is the selected item. If you move focus away, the text still stays there.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TryOutArea.PickerPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Tap in picker, when list appears click Cancel, and then type on the physical keyboard." />
            <Picker x:Name="picker"
                    Title="Select a monkey"
                    TitleColor="Red">
                <Picker.ItemsSource>
                    <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                        <x:String>Baboon</x:String>
                        <x:String>Capuchin Monkey</x:String>
                        <x:String>Blue Monkey</x:String>
                        <x:String>Squirrel Monkey</x:String>
                        <x:String>Golden Lion Tamarin</x:String>
                        <x:String>Howler Monkey</x:String>
                        <x:String>Japanese Macaque</x:String>
                    </x:Array>
                </Picker.ItemsSource>
            </Picker>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: can you please include some code.

Comment: Hi Amjad, I've add some code, hope it helps explain!

Comment: thanks you @sparky, so your problem is what? i dont see any issue in the code

Comment: I don't think there is a problem with the code, but it's that the picker allows free text to be entered when I don't think it should. In effect you can type anything in the picker, like the word "Random" for example, which then gives the impression "Random" is the selected item. Earlier versions of Xamarin Forms, for instance 3.5, would not allow text to be input - as soon as a key was typed on the keyboard, the list of items in the picker would be displayed.

Comment: why don't you use syncfusion combobox if you having troubles with picker that you dont want https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/combobox/getting-started

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Amjad, but the licence costs for Syncfusion would be prohibitive.

Comment: Struggling with the same issue. Any solution so far?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by implementing a custom ITextWatcher.

```
public class MyPickerRenderer : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.PickerRenderer
{
    public MyPickerRenderer(Context ctx) : base(ctx)
    {
    } 

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        EditText.AddTextChangedListener(new ReadonlyTextWatcher(EditText, Element));
    }
}

public class ReadonlyTextWatcher : Java.Lang.Object, ITextWatcher
{
    private readonly EditText textEdit;
    private readonly Picker picker;
    private string originalText;

    public ReadonlyTextWatcher(EditText textEdit, Picker picker)
    {
        this.textEdit = textEdit;
        this.picker = picker;
    }

    public void AfterTextChanged(IEditable s)
    {
        string newText = s.ToString();
        bool mustUndo = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(newText) && !picker.Items.Contains(newText);

        if (mustUndo)
        {
            textEdit.SetText(originalText, TextView.BufferType.Normal);
        }
    }

    public void BeforeTextChanged(ICharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
    {
        originalText = s.ToString();
    }

    public void OnTextChanged(ICharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
    {
    }
}
```